# replace every second line of my triangle with a blank line for loops

Tags: java, netbeans

instead of getting a full triangle with 5 lines of `"*"` how do I replace every second line with a blank line, e.g. to look like this

```
  5   

 555 

55555
```

This is my code:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

     for(int j = i; j < 5; j++) {

         System.out.print(" ");

     }

    for(int k = 0; k <= (i*2); k++) {

        System.out.print("5");
    }
       System.out.println(); 
}
```

Comment: Just add another `System.out.println();` after the existing one

Comment: System.out.println(); twice?

Comment: You can also change your existing `System.out.println();` to   `System.out.println(System.lineSeparator());`

Comment: Can you please clearly show what you want the output to look like? Do you want 5s or *s? Do you want 3 non blank lines or 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need small modification in your code and you can get what you want.

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

         for(int j = i; j < 5; j++) {

             System.out.print(" ");

         }

        for(int k = 0; k <= (i*2); k++) {
            if(i%2==0)
            System.out.print("*");
        }
           System.out.println(); 
    }
```

check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just test for `i % 2`

```
      for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

             for(int j = i; j < 5; j++) {

                 System.out.print(" ");

             }

             for(int k = 0; k <= (i*2); k++) {

                 System.out.print(i % 2 == 0 ? "*" : " ");
             }
             System.out.println();
        }
```

**edit**

If you want to print `5` instead or `*` then modify the code to use `5`

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis I am confused at to what the *correct* output should be.  The OP posted using the `5` char but mentions using `*` - Or  are you meaning something else?

Comment: Yeah, it's not entirely clear to me what the OP wants either, but you have the extra `System.out.println();` at the top of the loop.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis Thanks, I have removed that

Answer (score 1):

```
     //try this code. It may help you to achieve your output


    [Check screen shot for the output of the below code][1]

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
      {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5 - i; j++) 
        {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) 
        {
         if(i%2!=0)
         {
            System.out.print(" ");
         }
         else{
            System.out.print("* ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Your output is 100% wrong as there are no spaces before * pattern in your screenshot.

Comment: now the code is changed. I think this time its work correctly

Answer (score 1):

**Check this:**

int num= 5; // 'num' denotes the number of lines

```
    int numOfSpaces; 

    for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        if( i%2 != 0)  // checks whether the line number is odd. If odd, prints '*'
        {
            numOfSpaces = (num-i) / 2; // find the number of blank spaces
             for(int j = 1; j <= numOfSpaces; j++) {
                   System.out.print(" ");
               }
              for(int k = 1; k <= i; k++) {  // number of '*'s to be printed = current line number = i
                  System.out.print("*");
              }
                 System.out.println(); 
        }

        else{
              System.out.println(); // leaves every second line blank (ie.,if line number is even.)
       }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Code below is Working now.**

> A simple `if` condition will solve your problem. Just check if the
>   value of `i` is divisible by **2**. If it is true then print a
>   **blank** line. Else Print `*` and you are done!

`*` will be printed on 1st, 3rd and 5th lines.

`Blank Space` will be printed on 2nd and 4th lines.

```
public class PrintPattern{
     public static void main(String []args){
         int lineNo=0; // New Variable for Line Number (Can Use variable 'i' also)
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            lineNo++;
            for(int j = i; j < 5; j++) {
                System.out.print(" "); 
            }

            if(lineNo%2!=0){
                for(int k = 0; k <= (i*2); k++) 
                    System.out.print('*'); // Will print '*' (or '5') Sequence for Odd Lines - 1st, 3rd, 5th Lines
                System.out.println();
                }
            else
                System.out.println();// Will print Blank Line for Even Lines - 2nd and 4th Lines
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I don't know 100% what the OP exactly wants, but I know the output for your code is completely incorrect.

Comment: According to question posted, I have written the code. And according to me it is what the person is asking for. Now if you mean that the code needs to display `5` instead of `*` then just replace that character.

Comment: Your code does not print what you advertise it to print. Have you tried running it? It prints 4 new lines in between the line with 3 *s and 7 *s

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have made changes in the code and added comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

     for(int j = i; j < 5; j++) {

         System.out.print(" ");

     }

    for(int k = 0; k <= (i*2); k++) {

        System.out.print("5");   //Use 5 instaed of * to draw
    }
       System.out.println(); 
       System.out.println();     //This one will solve your problem
}
```

**Output will be:**

```
     5                                                                                                                                                                   

    555                                                                                                                                                                  

   55555                                                                                                                                                                 

  5555555                                                                                                                                                                

 555555555
```

Comment: The question is *how to replace every second line with a blank*

Answer (score -3):

I think that you can just enter one more print statement inside the loop:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

     System.out.println();

     for(int j = i; j < 5; j++) {

         System.out.print(" ");

     }

     for(int k = 0; k <= (i*2); k++) {

         System.out.print("*");
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Output

```
     *

    ***

   *****

  *******

 *********
```

Comment: The question how to *replace every second line with a blank*

Comment: Yes, my question is how to replace every second line with a blank, not how to put a blank between each line. I would like a triangle size 5 to print 3 lines showing a character and 2 lines of blank between the character lines.